# If an integral is divergant with a non-negative intigrand, than the limit of the antiderivative is infinite

Tags: calculus, integration

Somebody asked me this question in calculus 2, which I've already done, but I finished it in like a year so I don't really remember that much.

The question is : "if $f(x)$ is a non-negative and continuous function in $(a,b] $, and  $ \int_a^bf(x)dx $ is divergent, then $ \lim_{ x\to a} \int_x^bf(t)dt = \infty$".

This is assuming that it is not bounded on $(a,b]$. The definition of a divergent integral is that the limit which I described does not exist.

Intuitively I was thinking that because $f(x)$ is non-negative, than it means that the anti-derivative is non-decreasing, but I forgot some things in calculus, so I could use your help.

Comment: This is impossible. If $f:[a,b]\to\Bbb{R}$ is continuous, then it is certainly bounded and Riemann-integrable (in the proper sense), so $\int_a^bf$ always exists. So, for your question to be non-trivial you have to drop the continuity hypothesis.

Comment: You're right, the function is continuous at $ (a,b] $. wow I forgot a lot of calculus...

Comment: Show that $F(x) = \int_x^b f(t) dt$ is decreasing on $(a,b]$ (think FTC). It follows that the limit exists if $F$ is bounded above.  Hence $\lim_{x \to a} F(x) = \infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f$ is non-negative, the function $F:(a,b]\to [0,\infty)$ defined as $F(x)=\int_x^bf$ will be (weakly) decreasing. So, $\lim\limits_{x\to a^-}F(x)$ always exists in $[0,\infty]$ (in fact, it equals $\sup\limits_{x\in (a,b]}F(x)$), and the question is whether the limit is finite or infinite. But, you're told that "$\int_a^bf$ is divergent", which means either:

- $\lim_{x\to a^-}\int_x^bf$ is $\pm \infty$ or
- $\lim_{x\to a^-}\int_x^bf$ does not even exist in $[-\infty,\infty]$

Well, like I mentioned above, since $F$ is a (weakly) decreasing function, the second option is not possible. So, only the first option is possible. Hence
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to a^-}F(x)=\lim_{x\to a^-}\int_x^bf = \infty.
\end{align}

Comment: Why is the first option is the only one possible?

Comment: @TomerC. do you agree that for any (weakly) decreasing function, $\lim_{x\to a^-}F(x)=\sup_{x\in (a,b]}F(x)$, so this always exists in $[-\infty,\infty]$?

Comment: Bounded increasing or decreasing functions have a limit. Hence the function must be unbounded. Since it's decreasing and the limit does not exist, the limit from the right must be $\infty$.